# Apache reverse proxy - URL without / is refused

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I use reverse proxy to show backend server content for a subdomain.
The subdomain.mydomain.com (server A) should display content of server with IP 123.123.123.123 port 1111 (server B).

Virtual host of subdomain.mydomain.com (server A):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com

SSLEngine on
SecAuditEngine On
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
LogLevel warn

<Directory />
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Location />
    ProxyPass https://123.123.123.123:1111
    ProxyPassReverse https://123.123.123.123:1111
</Location>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/chain_wildcard_site_combined.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/key_wildcard_site.key
 
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>                                  
</IfModule>
```

Virtual host of 123.123.123.123:1111 (server B):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:1111>
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/site/htdocs

SSLEngine on
RewriteEngine On
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPreserveHost On
LogLevel warn

<Location "/">
   Require ip 222.222.222.222
</Location>

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/www/site/htdocs>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /srv/www/site/log/error.log
CustomLog /srv/www/site/log/access.log combined
CustomLog /srv/www/site/log/ssl_request_log \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/chain_wildcard_site_combined.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/cert.site/key_wildcard_site.key

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If I load URL:
https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir/

it loads successfully.

If I load URL (without trailing slash):
https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir

it results error page: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

**EDIT1:**

I execute command:

```
curl -IL https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir
```

and I get this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 13:45:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
Location: https://subdomain.mydomain.com:1111/dir/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

curl: (7) Failed to connect to subdomain.mydomain.com port 1111: Connection refused
```

**EDIT2:**

I added trailing slash

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass https://123.123.123.123:1111/
    ProxyPassReverse https://123.123.123.123:1111/
</Location>
```

But I still get the **Connection refused** error.

Any idea why is it resulting error, when trailing slash is missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I would try adding the trailing slash to the `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` directives in your location block. From what I see in doc and own config, you can write `ProxyPass "/" "something_with_trailing_slash/"` or `ProxyPass "/url" "something_without_trailing_slash"`, while your location block is equivalent to `ProxyPass "/" "something_without_trailing_slash`

Comment: Earlier I used the `ProxyPass "/" "something_with_trailing_slash/"`with the same wrong result.

Comment: do both `curl -IL https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir` and `curl -IL https://subdomain.mydomain.com/dir/` and edit the question to include the output.

Comment: @mforsetti added curl result into OP

Answer (score 1):

Review your firewall settings and your server logs on server B and verify that server A is able to reach server B with the correct IP address as sender (I'm assuming that's 222.222.222.222). Your listings for server B are also missing a `Listen 1111 https` directive.

*edit*
The backend server is forcing a redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://subdomain.mydomain.com:1111/dir/
```

That the HSTS header is present and the absence of any rewrite rules makes me assume that it's the application that's issuing the redirect.

Verify which it is.

You stated that with the added '/' things work fine. Forcing the trailing '/' with `mod_rewrite` on the frontend server seems like an acceptable solution to me.

Comment: I missed to mention, that Listen 1111, 443 is set separately in ports.conf. I don't think it is a firewall problem, as it works for /dir/ but not works for /dir

Comment: Find out what triggers the redirect you experience according to `curl`'s output. It's very likely that it's the backend server (non-obvious from the config fragments you posted) or the application itself that's forcing it. Enforcing a trailing `/` with rewrite rules could be an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was already answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1670420/apache-reverse-proxy-url-without-is-refused). Still to answer your question,

*You are missing a forward-slash at the end of both the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives.*

Read [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) if you need more details on why this is the case.

Comment: I tested your suggestion, but I still get the error. See the modified OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your reverse proxy is not (probably should not be) listening on port 1111.

Yet, your 123 server is redirecting to port 1111 (assumption based on configs you posted).